# SpamAssassin TVD_SPACE_RATIO_MINFP

Tags: php, spamassasin

При проверке письма в SpamAssassin выдает:

> -2.749 TVD_SPACE_RATIO_MINFP   TVD_SPACE_RATIO_MINFP

Что это за параметр такой (нигде нет нормального описания)? Как это исправить? Письмо отправляю при помощи `mail()`.

Comment: Видимо у вас в письме слишком много пробелов по отношению к непробельным символам. Если у вас есть форматирование текста отступами из пробелов то избавьтесь от него. Так же убедитесь, что в конце строк нет лишних пробелов до завершения строк

Comment: пробовал стирать всё, писать для примеру 123 - без толку

Comment: *нигде нет нормального описания* — а в официальной документации — [есть](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/TVD_SPACE_RATIO).

Comment: забил, глючный сервис, 5 раз страницу обновляешь и каждый раз новая оценка, бред...

Answer (score 3):

в официальной документации это правило, конечно, [описано](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/TVD_SPACE_RATIO).

> According to a comment in the rules file "it's the ratio of spaces to non-spaces in each paragraph. apparently messages where generally there are lots of spaces mean the message is spam."
>
> Extra space in HTML messages will be ignored in mail clients, but may not be ignored in pattern-matching filters. Slightly different messages may be sent to each recipient to avoid filtering.

мой вольный перевод:

> согласно комментарию к правилу, «это отношение пробельных символов (пробелы, символы табуляции) к не-пробельным в каждом параграфе. очевидно, что сообщения с большим количеством пробельных символов — это спам».
>
> излишние пробельные символы в html-сообщениях игнорируются почтовыми клиентами, но не могут быть проигнорированы в фильтрах, использующих pattern-matching. слегка отличающиеся сообщения могут быть отосланы каждому получателю во избежание отфильтровывания.